# Django rest framework default value random identifier

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I'm trying to debug a weird behaviour when I try to save a DynamicDocument in MongoEngine. 
The document class is declared as follows:

```
class Command(DynamicDocument):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'executor_data_commands'
    }

    name = StringField()
    args = DynamicField()
    issued_at = LongField(default=time.time())
    sync_with_kafka = BooleanField(default=False)
    correlation_id = StringField(
        default=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
    )
    commands_output = DynamicField(default=None)

    @classmethod
    def post_save(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        """
        Send data to Kafka executor data topic after a new instance has been saved
        :param sender: the sender who emitted the signal
        :param document: the saved instance
        """
        if kwargs['created']:
            CommandHandler(document).send_command()



class CommandHandler:
    """
    Command handler class
    """

    def __init__(self, command_instance):
        self.command_instance = command_instance

    def send_command(self):
        """
        Send command to Kafka queue and save the response in the
        local database
        :return: True if message is published over Kafka channel
        False otherwise
        """
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json",
            "Accept": "application/vnd.kafka.v2+json"
        }

        logger_kafka_handlers.info(
            "Got new command: %s - %s" % (self.command_instance.name, self.command_instance.args))

        args = self.command_instance.args
        if 'machine_identifier' in args:
            args['machine_identifier'] = MACHINE_MAPPING.get(args['machine_identifier'], args['machine_identifier'])

        response = requests.post(
            KAFKA_BROKER_EXECUTOR_COMMANDS_IN['host'],
            json={"records": [{"value": {
                "name": self.command_instance.name,
                "args": args,
                "correlation_id": self.command_instance.correlation_id,
                "issued_ts": time.time()
            }}]},
            headers=headers,
            auth=(KAFKA_BROKER_EXECUTOR_COMMANDS_IN['user'], KAFKA_BROKER_EXECUTOR_COMMANDS_IN['password'])

        )

        self.command_instance.sync_with_kafka = True if response.status_code == 200 else False
        self.command_instance.save()
        logger_kafka_handlers.info(
        "Handled new command; Name: %s - Args: %s - Sync with Kafka: %s; CorrelationId: %s" % (
            self.command_instance.name, self.command_instance.args, self.command_instance.sync_with_kafka,
            self.command_instance.correlation_id))
```

So I expect that created document will have a 10 letters random *correlation_id* and passed to the *post_save* handler which basically performs an HTTP request and logs the instance fields.

The issue is related the *correlation_id* field: 
it seems that the default value assigned to each saved instance is equal to another one saved in the db.

I exclude under-the-hood update query as well as some variable reassignments since the issue is clearly visible when logging the instance fields in the last line of *send_command* method.

Ideas?

Thanks, 
FB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your understanding of `default` value.

I am not sure about the mongo DynamicDocument but i'd assume that it will be same behavior as normal model.

So,
from the documentation:

> The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable
>   object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is
>   created.

In your case, it is not callable, so it is called only once when model class is created.

You need to make it callable, so move the implemenation to a function:

```
def generate_random_corr():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
```

And use it in the model class like this:

```
 correlation_id = StringField(default=generate_random_corr)
```

Same applies to the other field:

```
issued_at = LongField(default=time.time())
```

Time will be the same for all objects.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I supposed there was something tricky but I didn't expect something like this! I'll let you know! Thanks for the tip!